# How to execute command for 2 location using PHP exec()

Tags: php, exec

I need to create a website that utilizes 2 existing encryption `CMD.exe` in PHP.

I know that you can use `exec()` to open `CMD` file in PHP, but currently my situation is I will need to type like this

```
D:\temp\userA>d:\myprogfolder\myprog /u r
```

in my command so that the program will works, in which the `D:\temp\userA` contains all the file that I need to encrypt and after `>` is the location of my exe file.

As you can see, they are both in different locations. So for `exec()`, I don't know how to write a command that can fit into `exec()` as I try to fill the above line into `exec()` and it doesn't run.

Is there a way so that I can combine the location of my file that I want to encrypt and exe location into one line and pass it to `exec()`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the working directory before executing the command:

```
chdir("D:\temp\userA");
exec("myprogfolder\myprog /u r");
```